# Node-Red + Arduino nodes - distinguish long press of push button from short one

Tags: arduino, node-red

My setup is a PC with running Node-Red and Arduino Mega (standard Firmata) plugged via USB. I also have a push button wired to the Arduino's pin. I can read the state of the button, but I would like to distinguish a long press from a short one. For example:

- short press - power toggle switch #1
- medium press - power toggle switch #2
- long press - power off all switches.

How can I achieve this? Do I need to write some function (I'd be glad for a little help here too, as I am no programmer) or I just have not found yet dedicated nodes?

The second scenario is not to distinguish the length but the number of times a button was pushed (in 0.5 sec for example):

- 1 time -  power toggle switch #1
- 2 times - power toggle switch #2
- 3 times - power off all switches.

Is this easier to achieve?

Best regards,

Jakub

Comment: This is a pretty broad question for this forum.  If you can show the code you've got so far, we can probably point you in the right direction.  But starting from "I'm no programmer" means we'd have a lot of ground to cover.

Answer (score 0):

You will certainly have to write a function on the Arduino to have it generate some form of a message that can be sent to Node-Red.

You could use the serial interface of the Arduino to send it to the pc over the USB port and have Node-Red listen to the serial port. There are plenty of examples for Arduino to start with (a lot of them in the Arduino IDE itsself).